# hive:how to get last 3 month total spend when use join

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to  get last 3 month total spend when use join source1 and source2 then get target table?

source1:

```
+--------+----------+
| cst_id |   date   |
+--------+----------+
| a      | 20180125 |
| b      | 20180627 |
| c      | 20181122 |
| d      | 20180304 |
+--------+----------+
```

source2:
join source1 and source2 table

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| cst_id | month  | spend |
+--------+--------+-------+
| a      | 201710 |   6.2 |
| a      | 201711 |   0.5 |
| a      | 201712 |   4.3 |
| a      | 201801 |   6.5 |
| a      | 201802 |     7 |
| a      | 201803 |    11 |
| a      | 201804 |    23 |
| a      | 201805 |    67 |
| a      | 201806 |   8.1 |
| a      | 201807 |   0.2 |
| a      | 201808 |   9.1 |
| a      | 201809 |     1 |
| a      | 201810 |     5 |
| a      | 201811 |     6 |
| a      | 201812 |     9 |
| b      | 201710 |   6.2 |
| b      | 201711 |   0.5 |
| b      | 201712 |   4.3 |
| b      | 201801 |   6.5 |
| b      | 201802 |     7 |
| b      | 201803 |    11 |
| b      | 201804 |    23 |
| b      | 201805 |    67 |
| b      | 201806 |   8.1 |
| b      | 201807 |   0.2 |
| b      | 201808 |   9.1 |
| b      | 201809 |     1 |
| b      | 201810 |     5 |
| b      | 201811 |     6 |
| b      | 201812 |     9 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

target table：
finally,every cst_id only get one row

```
+--------+----------+-----------------+
| cst_id |   date   | last3monthSpend |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
| a      | 20180125 |              11 |
| b      | 20180627 |             101 |
+--------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What are the data types of the `date` and `month` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using `join`, `group by`, and window functions.  The following shows the logic:

```
select s1.cst_id, s1.date, sum(s1.spend)
from (select s1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s2.cst_id order by s2.month desc) as seqnum
      from source1 s1 join 
           source2 s2
           on s2.cst_id = s1.cst_id and
              s2.month < s1.date
     ) s
where seqnum <= 3
group by s1.cst_id, s1.date;
```

The only issue is how to compare the `date` and `month` column.  This version works if the values are strings.

Comment: could this way works too?"SELECT * from table where date >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'"

Comment: @CD_Lee . . . No.  The rows that you want are relative to the date in the first source.